How can I improve insulation in a basement bedroom?
So the past few winters, the bedroom on the 2nd floor of my 1950s home would get unbearably cold. I assumed that it was because there was no insulation behind the wall that faces the front of the house. It would feel like the cold would just seep through the walls. I finally decided to cut a hole and take a look and do some investigating. As you can see in the pictures, I did find insulation but it appears to me that it’s too compressed. The distance between the brick and the drywall is about an inch, maybe an inch and a half.
What can I do to improve the heat retention in this room? This room also has two very old double hung windows which are due to be replaced. I usually put plastic over the windows anyway. I don’t think it’s the windows alone causing the room to reach those levels of cold, however. Would the recommendation be to remove the existing wall, install proper 2x4 framing so that the insulation has room to expand?
I’m afraid that doing all of that work will only marginally improve my situation. Is there something else I’m missing? Thanks!




You didn't say what kind of heat you're running. An air duct up but no return?

Yes, sorry. The 2nd floor has its own furnace so the other 2 bedrooms on the 2nd floor have no problem at all getting and staying warm.
And yes, I always place the plastic on the outside of the window trim.
If I do go the route of putting up new framing, on a scale of 1-10 how bad of an idea would it be to put up the framing on top of the existing drywall? Is that just being lazy because I don’t want to tear down the drywall first?

An inch of insulation is better than nothing - but if it's achieved by stuffing in a thicker piece and compressing it,, very little better than nothing because the trapped air is the important bit.  I assume you've got solid walls, and there isn't a cavity behind the concrete(?) blocks we can see

You are correct, the other side of those concrete blocks is the outside of the house.

Putting new framing up over the existing drywall will only save you the demo effort and lose you space in the room that you don't really need to.  Just bite the bullet and demo the drywall.  You can probably even leave the existing framing and sister 2x4s to them.

What's in the attic? Is your HVAC system serving the room properly? This wall insulation is a bit weak, but certainly not terrible. It's at least as good as the fiber gunk my 1950s home had.

With 2 other bedrooms on the 2nd floor able to be kept warm, I doubt the minimal insulation on the walls of this bedroom are to blame (unless the other two bedrooms have significantly more insulation than this one).
Walls aren't that of a problem for losing heat in winter. Most of the heat loss is through the ceiling, windows (that no matter how well insulated they are, they are still far below wall insulation (R value of 2 for regular double glazed), even at 1"-1.5" (R value of 3.5 per inch)) and air leakage (reference).
Checking the attic for insulation (and comparing with the space above the other 2 bedrooms) should be easy. Checking for air leakage is more difficult.
You might try to find an energy audit company to assess your house, inspect it with an infrared camera and do a blower door test. These inspections are often subsidized by the power companies and the government, so you should be able to find one for free. Once you have the results of the tests you can decide if you want a smaller DIY fix aimed at just this bedroom, or let the company fix everything (or any combination of work).
Finally, if the insulation and air leakage situation is similar throughout the 2nd story, it might be an issue with the furnace ducting - does the cold bedroom have the same size of air registers as the other bedrooms? Does it have a good return air path (a return grille in the room or a gap under the door to let air out)? Is there a damper for that room that's closed? A duct is crushed shut? A good HVAC technician could help with that investigation as well, but that would probably not be free.

Presumably (I'm not used to blown air systems) if a big room has the same size duct/grille as a small room, there's your problem as it's undersized.  But being at the end of a very long run of duct wouldn't help wither

The 2 other rooms I'm assuming have much better insulation because they were added to the house in 2005 (or something like that, much more modern). Those other 2 rooms also have an attic above them. The cold room does not have an attic above it as the ceiling in the room is sloped (gabled roof). On top of that, the room is definitely larger than the other 2 rooms and has only the one duct, I've thought about adding a duct but I can't really get access above that room because of the gabled roof. I'm assuming now that the sloped ceiling is just as big a problem as the wall?

Yes, that sounds about right. I would try to add insulation to the ceiling before doing anything to the walls - the benefits should be more pronounced and it should be simpler to do (avoiding windows and outlets). Redoing the HVAC ducting might also be possible, and could be done in parallel to adding insulation.

If it was me, I'd first make a budget and interface with contractors to see the various cost of things and options.  What do they recommend?  How much will it cost?
An essential and inexpensive tool that you may want to pick up is one of those gun type thermometers.  You can pin point where the cold is leaking into your home.   See pic below.
The insulation in the picture is basically doing nothing, so it needs to be replaced.  Can you do it with spray foam insulation?  Or should you use those solid pink sheets?  This is where contractor suggestions will help.
Then it becomes a business decision.  Do I pay one of these guys to do it, or do it myself with buddy or two?  Or do I just keep a space heater and electric blanket in the room?


I have an infrared camera that attaches to a phone that I used to discover sources of air leakage (around doors and windows, mostly). I'm not sure that a point-and-shoot thermometer can achieve the same result, unless you diligently map out of walls (in a grid pattern or similar). True, cameras are significantly more expensive, so it might be worth it to give the thermometer a try first, but I would caveat its use to find small leaks.

@EliIser yes, those IR thermometers are useful but they're sensitive over quite a wide area.  The laser dot only marks the middle of a big cone from which it collects.  So even mapping out is tricky.
